# Authorize.net Automated Recurring Billing Payments API

Tags: authorize.net, recurring-billing, authorize.net-arb

i am developing a website where Automated Recurring Billing is required.

Here i want to update database whenever payment will happen. in time of subscription i am able to update database.can you please inform me how can i call my php script for updating database in time of next occurrence of payments for the subscription?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Silent Post](http://www.johnconde.net/blog/all-about-authorize-nets-silent-post/). Silent Post is Authorize.Net's equivalent of Paypal's IPN. Silent Post will allow you to retrieve the information from each transaction "in the background" so you can update your database accordingly. This includes all subscription payments. [Implementing it in PHP is easy to do](http://www.johnconde.net/blog/handling-authorize-net-silent-post-with-php/).

They also now offer [Webhooks](http://www.johnconde.net/blog/handling-authorize-net-webhooks-with-php/) which is a bit more complicated than Silent Post but offers much more flexibility and power.

(*Disclaimer, I wrote all articles*)

Comment: thanks for your help , but how can i test this using authorize.net, i have created one account in authorize.net,when i try to test my  another site, i always got an error 'Transactions of this market type cannot be processed on this system'.

Comment: Unfortunately the only way to test Silent Post is to send your own form submissions to it. The form in my first link should make that easy for you to do. Once it works with that form it will definitely work when you go live.